# Steam backup restoration stops after disk 1

Tags: steam, the-witcher

As the title states it, the restoration process (The Witcher) stops at disk 1 and doesn't ask for disk 2 or 3. Only 4.7 GB is restored and I have to download the rest (~6 GB).

How can I make it work ?

Comment: Did you do the backup to disk yourself?  If so, I would copy all the backup files to 3 folders (Disk 1, Disk 2, and Disk 3, which I think are the same names Steam uses) on your hard drive.  I don't know if that's the actual solution which is why I'm not posting as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll post as an answer then.  Don't forget to [accept it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Copy the contents of each disk to a folder on your hard drive named `Disk X` where `X` is the disk number, and then perform the restoration.  I would suggest that you have only these folders in a parent folder, but that might not be totally necessary.  It seems that Steam isn't smart enough to ask you to insert the next disk.